# Problem with bootstrapping pages in Magnolia 6.2

Tags: magnolia

I'm trying to bootstrap page so it will be available on different servers after deployment new WAR file.

Here are steps what I did:

- design MyPage page in author Page app on local dev server
- open JCR App and export MyPage page as yaml and xml into tmp folder
- delete existing MyPage from Page app (it's only marked as deleted)
- stop server with deployed magnolia-cms-webapp

1st attempt: bootstrap as page belongs to module "myModule"

```
magnolia-cms-webapp\src\main\resources\META-INF\magnolia\myModule.xml
magnolia-cms-webapp\src\main\resources\mgnl-bootstrap\myModule\website.MyPage.xml
```

- build and start server
- confirm that page wasn't bootstrapped

2nd attempt: bootstrap as page in WEB-INF\bootstrap\common folder

```
magnolia-cms-webapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\bootstrap\common\website.MyPage.xml
```

- build and start server
- confirm that page wasn't bootstrapped

I've tried both YAML and XML exported files

What else I can try?

Comment: Should work. Any errors in the log files?

Comment: It may not work if the module which brings the page had been already installed.

Comment: @Ducaz035 - Yes. Module had been installed. After I remove it in JCR app and redeploy I successfully bootstrap pages. Thank you. Please post your answer so I can mark it.

Comment: any idea why bootstrapping attempt in `magnolia-cms-webapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\bootstrap\common\website.MyPage.xml` not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrapping files only happens while installing a module. If the module had been already installed, adding files won't have any effect on the instance.